# error while compiling application with pyinstaller [eel]

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, eel

Earlier, when compiling a script using pyinstaller, everything was fine. I run like this.

```
python -m eel stat1.py web --onefile --noconsole
```

Now I get this error. What could be the problem? I used to build an application in python 3.7, now 3.9 the script itself is launched via the console.

> Building executable with main script 'stat1.py' and web folder
> 'web'...
>
> Running: pyinstaller stat1.py --hidden-import bottle_websocket
> --add-data C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\eel\eel.js;eel
> --add-data web;web --onefile --noconsole
>
> 720 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.5.1 720 INFO: Python: 3.9.4 720 INFO:
> Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0 720 INFO: wrote
> C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\Desktop\stat\stat1.spec 728 INFO: UPX is not
> available. 730 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
> ['C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\Desktop\stat',
> 'C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\Desktop\stat'] Fatal Python error:
> init_import_site: Failed to import the site module Python runtime
> state: initialized Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site.py",
> line 73, in 
> import os   File "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\os.py",
> line 27, in 
> import stat as st   File "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\Desktop\stat\stat.py", line 1, in 
> import pyodbc, datetime,time,eel, jinja2   File "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\eel_*init*_.py",
> line 5, in 
> from gevent.threading import Timer   File "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\gevent_*init*_.py",
> line 62, in 
> import socket  # pylint:disable=unused-import,useless-suppression   File
> "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\socket.py",
> line 67, in 
> **all**.extend(os._get_exports_list(*socket)) AttributeError: partially initialized module 'os' has no attribute '*get_exports_list'
> (most likely due to a circular import) 811 INFO: checking Analysis 811
> INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent 811
> INFO: Initializing module dependency graph... 811 INFO: Caching module
> graph hooks... 821 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ... Fatal Python
> error: init_import_site: Failed to import the site module Python
> runtime state: initialized Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site.py",
> line 73, in 
> import os   File "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\os.py",
> line 27, in 
> import stat as st   File "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\Desktop\stat\stat.py", line 1, in 
> import pyodbc, datetime,time,eel, jinja2   File "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\eel_*init**.py",
> line 5, in 
> from gevent.threading import Timer   File "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\gevent_*init**.py",
> line 62, in 
> import socket  # pylint:disable=unused-import,useless-suppression   File
> "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\socket.py",
> line 67, in 
> **all**.extend(os._get_exports_list(*socket)) AttributeError: partially initialized module 'os' has no attribute '*get_exports_list'
> (most likely due to a circular import) Fatal Python error:
> init_import_site: Failed to import the site module Python runtime
> state: initialized Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site.py",
> line 73, in 
> import os   File "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\os.py",
> line 27, in 
> import stat as st   File "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\Desktop\stat\stat.py", line 1, in 
> import pyodbc, datetime,time,eel, jinja2   File "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\eel_*init**.py",
> line 5, in 
> from gevent.threading import Timer   File "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\gevent_*init**.py",
> line 62, in 
> import socket  # pylint:disable=unused-import,useless-suppression   File
> "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\socket.py",
> line 67, in 
> **all**.extend(os._get_exports_list(*socket)) AttributeError: partially initialized module 'os' has no attribute '*get_exports_list'
> (most likely due to a circular import) 3796 INFO: Processing pre-find
> module path hook distutils from
> 'C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\pre_find_module_path\hook-distutils.py'.
> 3796 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir
> 'C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib'
> 11296 INFO: Caching module dependency graph... 11467 INFO: running
> Analysis Analysis-00.toc 11477 INFO: Adding
> Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final
> executable   required by
> C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
> 11539 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll
> dependency of
> C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python39.dll
> 11570 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\Desktop\stat\stat1.py
> 11577 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'bottle_websocket' 11793 INFO:
> Processing module hooks... 11793 INFO: Loading module hook
> 'hook-difflib.py' from
> 'C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
> 11793 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.py' from
> 'C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
> 11793 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.util.py' from
> 'C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
> 11793 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from
> 'C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
> Fatal Python error: init_import_site: Failed to import the site module
> Python runtime state: initialized Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File
> "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site.py",
> line 73, in 
> import os   File "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\os.py",
> line 27, in 
> import stat as st   File "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\Desktop\stat\stat.py", line 1, in 
> import pyodbc, datetime,time,eel, jinja2   File "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\eel_*init**.py",
> line 5, in 
> from gevent.threading import Timer   File "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\gevent_*init**.py",
> line 62, in 
> import socket  # pylint:disable=unused-import,useless-suppression   File
> "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\socket.py",
> line 67, in 
> **all**.extend(os._get_exports_list(*socket)) AttributeError: partially initialized module 'os' has no attribute '*get_exports_list'
> (most likely due to a circular import) 11878 INFO: Loading module hook
> 'hook-gevent.py' from
> 'C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
> Fatal Python error: init_import_site: Failed to import the site module
> Python runtime state: initialized Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File
> "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site.py",
> line 73, in 
> import os   File "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\os.py",
> line 27, in 
> import stat as st   File "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\Desktop\stat\stat.py", line 1, in 
> import pyodbc, datetime,time,eel, jinja2   File "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\eel_*init**.py",
> line 5, in 
> from gevent.threading import Timer   File "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\gevent_*init**.py",
> line 62, in 
> import socket  # pylint:disable=unused-import,useless-suppression   File
> "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\socket.py",
> line 67, in 
> **all**.extend(os._get_exports_list(*socket)) AttributeError: partially initialized module 'os' has no attribute '*get_exports_list'
> (most likely due to a circular import) 12328 INFO: Determining a
> mapping of distributions to packages... 40832 WARNING: Unable to find
> package for requirement zope.event from package gevent. 40832 WARNING:
> Unable to find package for requirement zope.interface from package
> gevent. 40832 INFO: Packages required by gevent: ['cffi', 'greenlet',
> 'setuptools'] 41936 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook
> setuptools.extern.six.moves from
> 'C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\pre_safe_import_module\hook-setuptools.extern.six.moves.py'.
> Fatal Python error: init_import_site: Failed to import the site module
> Python runtime state: initialized Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File
> "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site.py",
> line 73, in 
> import os   File "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\os.py",
> line 27, in 
> import stat as st   File "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\Desktop\stat\stat.py", line 1, in 
> import pyodbc, datetime,time,eel, jinja2   File "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\eel_*init**.py",
> line 5, in 
> from gevent.threading import Timer   File "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\gevent_*init**.py",
> line 62, in 
> import socket  # pylint:disable=unused-import,useless-suppression   File
> "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\socket.py",
> line 67, in 
> **all**.extend(os._get_exports_list(_socket)) AttributeError: partially initialized module 'os' has no attribute '_get_exports_list'
> (most likely due to a circular import) pre-safe-import-module hook
> failed, needs fixing.

Comment: maybe don't use the newest Python because some modules may not be ready to work with this version.

Answer (score 1):

To include support for HTML templating, currently using Jinja2 I think thats the problem since your using web:

`pip install eel[jinja2]`

Comment: I installed ell like that

Comment: have you tried re installing it?

Comment: apparently when I installed a new version of python, I did not completely clean the old one. Everything was assembled on the virtual machine without any problems.